# Javaslang / Vavr LinkedHashMap from List

Tags: list, linkedhashmap, vavr

Is there a concise, idiomatic way to create an order-preserving map from a Javaslang / Vavr `List`? `List.toMap()` returns a plain `HashMap`, so that doesn't do it. What I have right now is something like this --

```
listOfKeys.foldLeft(
    LinkedHashMap.<Key, Value>.empty(), 
    (m, k) -> m.put(k, valueFor(k))
);
```

-- but this seems more verbose than necessary, and possibly less efficient as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Value.collect`](http://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.0/io/vavr/Value.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) method (inherited by `List`) is usually used for this purpose, which is analogous to the Java 8 Stream's [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) method. It takes a collector to perform a *mutable reduction* (see note). Vavr [`LinkedHashMap`](http://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.0/io/vavr/collection/LinkedHashMap.html) provides a static [`collector()`](http://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.0/io/vavr/collection/LinkedHashMap.html#collector--) method, so you can use that to get an instance to a collector which will collect to a `LinkedHashMap`.

```
listOfKeys.map(key -> new Tuple2<>(key, valueForKey(key)))
    .collect(LinkedHashMap.collector());
```

I'm not sure how it will perform compared to your solution though, I don't think it will have a difference in performance, but as an added bonus it's compatible with the JDK collectors, so you can use that to collect to JDK collections easily.

* Note that since the Vavr collections are immutable, *mutable reduction* isn't actually mutable in this context.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a [`toLinkedMap()`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.0/io/vavr/Value.html#toLinkedMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) now.
Hope it can help here.